# why first row of data half imported to datagridview and the rest all imported?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

As show [in this screen recording](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zsmt0F3jv2Y&feature=youtu.be) I have two datagridviews `dgv1` and `dgv2` with three columns two `DataGridViewTextBox` columns and a `DataGridViewCheckBox` Column, I have create some rows for `dgv1`.

```
dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Descripton", typeof(string)));

dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Grant", "the couch guy" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mike", "the pizza guy" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Lee", "don't cross me guy" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Adamn", "the number guy" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Freddy", "I love my pork chops" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Gus", "Me and my chicken" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Walt", "i love my blue" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Saul", "mind you, I'm a lawyer" });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Jessy", "i need to charge my batteries" });

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = dt1.Columns[0].ColumnName;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = dt1.Columns[1].ColumnName;
```

I have written code to send data to `dgv2`, data will be sent as rows at each checked event. so I have used the events, `CellValueChnaged()` and `CurrentCellDirtyStateChnaged().` [In this link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/nocn3wyt92ttatm/dgvRowBinding.rar) contains the code, what funny about this is it imports half of the data of the first row of the clicked rows and rest it imports successfully, I was trying figureout whats the problem is hours but not a single clue by the way : (

could any one see the problem with this code?

here is the complete code:

```
namespace dgvRowBinding
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt1;
        DataTable dt2;
        bool isDataReady = false;

        TreeNode tnOne;
        TreeNode tnTwo;
        TreeNode tnThree;
        TreeNode tnFour;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tnOne = new TreeNode("Node #1");
            tnOne.Tag = 1;

            tnTwo = new TreeNode("Node #2");
            tnTwo.Tag = 2;

            tnThree = new TreeNode("Node #3");
            tnThree.Tag = 3;

            tnFour = new TreeNode("Node #4");
            tnFour.Tag = 4;

            tv.Nodes.Add(tnOne);
            tv.Nodes.Add(tnTwo);
            tv.Nodes.Add(tnThree);
            tv.Nodes.Add(tnFour);

            dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Descripton", typeof(string)));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Grant", "the couch guy" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mike", "the pizza guy" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Lee", "don't cross me guy" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Adamn", "the number guy" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Freddy", "I love my pork chops" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Gus", "Me and my chicken" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Walt", "i love my blue" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Saul", "mind you, I'm a lawyer" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Jessy", "i need to charge my batteries" });

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = dt1.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = dt1.Columns[1].ColumnName;


            isDataReady = true;

            dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (isDataReady)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].Value) == true)
                    {
                        DataRow dr1 = ((DataRowView)(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem)).Row;

                        dt2.ImportRow(dr1);

                        dt2.Columns[0].ColumnName = dt1.Columns[0].ColumnName;
                        dt2.Columns[1].ColumnName = dt1.Columns[1].ColumnName;

                        dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
                        dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = dt2.Columns[0].ColumnName;
                        dataGridView2.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = dt2.Columns[1].ColumnName;
                    } 
                }
            }
            catch
            {                
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (isDataReady == true)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty == true)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    struct MyStruct
    {

    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: I am blind to rar. can you post the part of the code where you copy/send the data to the second datagridview?

Comment: I have updated the post with complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you changing `dataGridView2` properties on each click? You have to move the data source setting to the load. Try this. (just typed in here not tested)

```
namespace dgvRowBinding
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt1;
        DataTable dt2;
        bool isDataReady = false;

        TreeNode tnOne;
        TreeNode tnTwo;
        TreeNode tnThree;
        TreeNode tnFour;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tnOne = new TreeNode("Node #1");
            tnOne.Tag = 1;

            tnTwo = new TreeNode("Node #2");
            tnTwo.Tag = 2;

            tnThree = new TreeNode("Node #3");
            tnThree.Tag = 3;

            tnFour = new TreeNode("Node #4");
            tnFour.Tag = 4;

            tv.Nodes.Add(tnOne);
            tv.Nodes.Add(tnTwo);
            tv.Nodes.Add(tnThree);
            tv.Nodes.Add(tnFour);

            dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Descripton", typeof(string)));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Grant", "the couch guy" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mike", "the pizza guy" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Lee", "don't cross me guy" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Adamn", "the number guy" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Freddy", "I love my pork chops" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Gus", "Me and my chicken" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Walt", "i love my blue" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Saul", "mind you, I'm a lawyer" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Jessy", "i need to charge my batteries" });

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = dt1.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = dt1.Columns[1].ColumnName;


            isDataReady = true;

            dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));

            dt2.Columns[0].ColumnName = dt1.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            dt2.Columns[1].ColumnName = dt1.Columns[1].ColumnName;

            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
            dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = dt2.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            dataGridView2.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = dt2.Columns[1].ColumnName;

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (isDataReady)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].Value) == true)
                    {
                        DataRow dr1 = ((DataRowView)(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem)).Row;

                        dt2.ImportRow(dr1);

                    } 
                }
            }
            catch
            {                
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (isDataReady == true)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty == true)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    struct MyStruct
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that, so when bind columns of datagridview2 with dt2's in CellValueChanged(), the properties of datagridview2 changes I know datasource gets updated, but is there any other properties of datagridview2 gets changed?

Comment: nice to hear it solved your problem. you don't need to change the `DataGridView's` `AutoGenerateColumns` and `DataPropertyName` each time. Also no need to change the `ColumnName` property of `dt2` each time. it is overkill and redundant code